# I need to update multiple elements in xml file using dom python

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am a begginer using Python. What I am trying to do is to update the InvoiceStatus of a certain list of invoices - I want to update it to "N" instead of "A". Below the XML file extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<AuditFile>
    <Header>
        <AuditFileVersion>1.04_01</AuditFileVersion>
        <CompanyID>51630</CompanyID>
    </Header>
    <MasterFiles>
        <Customer>
            <CustomerID>20201376</CustomerID>
            <AccountID>20000</AccountID>
        </Customer>
    </MasterFiles>
    <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
            <NumberOfEntries>981</NumberOfEntries>
            <Invoice>
                <InvoiceNo>F2 UF/3510000211</InvoiceNo>
                <ATCUD>0</ATCUD>
                <DocumentStatus>
                    <InvoiceStatus>A</InvoiceStatus>
                    <SourceBilling>P</SourceBilling>
                </DocumentStatus>
                <InvoiceNo>F2 UF/3510020247</InvoiceNo>
                <ATCUD>0</ATCUD>
                <DocumentStatus>
                    <InvoiceStatus>A</InvoiceStatus>
                    <SourceBilling>P</SourceBilling>
                </DocumentStatus>
                <InvoiceNo>F2 UF/3510020247</InvoiceNo>
                <ATCUD>0</ATCUD>
                <DocumentStatus>
                    <InvoiceStatus>A</InvoiceStatus>
                    <SourceBilling>P</SourceBilling>
                </DocumentStatus>
            </Invoice>
        </SalesInvoices>
    </SourceDocuments>
</AuditFile>
```

Here the script:

```
 from xml.dom import minidom
 def reemplazaTexto(nodo,textonuevo):
        
    nodo.firstChild.replaceWholeText(textonuevo)

    doc = minidom.parse('sample.xml')
    print(doc.toxml())
    
    invoices = doc.getElementsByTagName('InvoiceStatus')
    
    for nodo in invoices:
        reemplazaTexto(nodo, 'N')
        
    print(doc.toxml())
```

But this script modifies all the InvoiceStatus. I would appreciate a hand on this.

Cheers,
Axel

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your goal is and how your attempted solution falls short. Which "certain invoices" do you want to modify?

Comment: Hello, I already fixed it. In case its usefull for someone:

Comment: from xml.dom import minidom
def reemplazaTexto(nodo,textonuevo):
    nodo.firstChild.replaceWholeText(textonuevo)
doc = minidom.parse('sample.xml')
invoicesIdsToChange = {'F2 UF/3510000260','F2 UF/3510000404'}
for invoiceElement in doc.getElementsByTagName('Invoice'):
    invoiceId = invoiceElement.getElementsByTagName('InvoiceNo')[0].firstChild.data
    if(invoiceId in invoicesIdsToChange): 
        invoiceElement.getElementsByTagName('InvoiceStatus')[0].firstChild.replaceWholeText('N')

fichero = open('sample.xml','w')
fichero.write(doc.toxml())
fichero.close

Comment: Thanks for following up! It would be more useful to share the code properly formatted though. You could do that here with Markdown or via a [pastebin](https://dpaste.com/?title=Axel+Oyhanarte+fix+for+SO+question+69962786&syntax=python)